# Grid based movement in Snake Game C++

Tags: c++, grid, lcd

I have basic knowledge of c++ and am trying to create a simple Snake game that will run on a 84 x 48 pixel LCD screen. The game works fine, but there is one thing I have been stuck on for a while, and I haven't found any help in any previous post:

so far, the movement of the snake is free, i.e. it moves pixel by pixel, meaning that, the snake  being composed of 3 x 3 pixel squares, most of the times it doesn't automatically align with the fruit. I would like to implement a "grid system", so turn my 84 x 48 game space into a 28 x 16 grid in which the snake moves and eats the fruit without the player having to adjust its trajectory many times before getting the right alignment with the fruit.

Here's the part of my code in which I print the snake to the screen:

```
void Snake::head_init(int size)
{

    _size = size;
    _x = (GRIDX/2 - _size/2)*_size; 
    _y = (GRIDY/2 - _size/2)*_size;

    printf("Snake initially at x = %i, y = %i\n", _x,_y);

}


void Snake::draw(N5110 &lcd)
{

    lcd.drawRect(_x,_y,_size,_size, FILL_BLACK);  // draw head

    for(int k = 0; k < _tail_length; k++) {
        lcd.drawRect(_tail_x[k],_tail_y[k],_size,_size, FILL_BLACK); // print tail
    }


}
```

GRIDX = 28, GRIDY = 16, _size = 3

I tried to multiply _x and _y by the size of the snake when printing it, but this doesn't give me the result I am aiming to.

Also, I would like the fruit to spawn in the same 28 x 16 grid.
Here is how my fruit is printed for now:

```
void Fruit::init(int size)
{
    _size = size;

    srand(time(NULL)); // initialise random number generator for fruit positions

    _x = rand() % 80 + 1; // generate a random x coordinate for fruit within the frame x range
    _y = rand() % 43 + 1; // generate a random y coordinate for fruit within the frame y range

    printf("Fruit initially at x = %i, y = %i \n", _x, _y); // print the random fruit coordinates over terminal
}

void Fruit::draw(N5110 &lcd)
{
lcd.drawSprite(_x,_y,3,3,(int *)fruit); // draw fruit at random position
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Be careful with `srand(time(NULL));` The general rule of thumb is to call `srand` once somewhere near the beginning of `main` It is unlikely that you need to reseed the generator after that, and if you do find one of these rare cases, odds are really good that `rand` is not the random number generator you want to be using.

Comment: what's your question? Where's your problem? How do you expect it and how does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: Recommendation run all of your code in 28x16 except the drawing code. Have the drawing code accept 28x16  and then do the appropriate math to convert to 84x48 when it draws. This way you only have to debug conversion errors on one place.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't understand how I could possibly do that... Could you plase detail your idea?

Comment: @tangoal it's all in the question!